# Google Admin console -- not finding Security -- to Manage API client access

Tags: security, oauth, admin, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to register an "Authorized API client" for a service account within Google Admin account page, as reference here:

https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/auth/service-accounts

After reading, within admin.google.com, there should be a section labeled "Security":

https://support.google.com/a/answer/162105?hl=en

1. Login to admin.google.com
2. Select 'Security -> Advanced Settings -> Authentication -> Manage
   third party OAuth Client access"

However, I am not finding "Security" upon page admin.google.com within either my account or administrator account.

Where is it or Why is it missing?

Comment: That document is for OAuth 1, which stopped accepting new users years ago. You are probably interested in OAuth 2: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2

Answer (score 0):

I realized what I was really trying to do is to provide access permissions to a specific 'client email' through the **Google Play Developers Console > Settings > USER ACCOUNTS & RIGHTS**